# WebFlux: how to work takeUntilOther() method?

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor, spring5

Can someone please explain how the `takeUntilOther()` method works? I tried to run the following code, but it shows nothing on my console.

```java
     Mono.just(10)
                .subscribe();

        Flux.range(1, 5)
                .takeUntilOther(Mono.just(10))
                .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

I don't understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kirill,

I'd suggest you referring to the appropriate part of [the project reactor's documentation](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#takeUntilOther-org.reactivestreams.Publisher-).

[image]

> `takeUntilOther(Publisher<?> other)` Relay values from this Flux until the given Publisher emits.

Meaning, you will be receiving values from the original Flux until given `Publisher<?> other` starts producing events. In your case, you have a [hot publisher](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/milestone/reference/#reactor.hotCold) `just()` that interrupts the original Flux immediately (by calling `cancel()` method).

I will give you one more example. Have a look at the following code snippet:

```
Flux.range(1, 5) // produces elements from 1 to 5
        .delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1)) // delays emission of each element from above for 1 second
        .takeUntilOther(Mono
                .just(10) // hot publisher. emits one element

                // delays '10' for 3 seconds. meaning that it will only 
                // appears in the original Flux in 3 seconds
                .delayElement(Duration.ofSeconds(3)) 
        )
        .subscribe(System.out::print);
```

The output is:

> 12

Comment: It doesn't work for me. The console output is empty

Comment: @KirillSereda, I assume the reason is that your application isn't waiting for the completion of the flux. I've prepared an example and pushed to https://github.com/TsybulskyStepan/stackoverflow. Please, use `./mvnw -pl flux-take-until-other clean spring-boot:run` in order to run it.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I have been release java sdk version 8 (not 11 as in your example). I changed to version 11 and it worked! =)

Comment: I'm glad that it was helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

Add Thread.sleep to wait the main thread (or what ever thread current code is running) so that subscriber thread will continue process. Here is the unit test version.

```
    @Test
    public void flux_Skip_Take_Based_On_Other_Streams() throws InterruptedException {
        
        Flux.range(1, 100) // publisher with elements from 1-100
                .delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1)) // Flux delay 1 sec before each element emit
                .skipUntilOther(Mono.just(10).delayElement(Duration.ofSeconds(10))) // skip the elements until inner Mono emits, i.e.  for 10 seconds
                .takeUntilOther(Mono.just(10).delayElement(Duration.ofSeconds(70))) // take the elements until inner mono emits, i.e. till 70 seconds
                .log()
                .subscribe();
    
        Thread.sleep(1000*100); //Sleep the main thread for 100 sec or more to verify the logs
}
```

output:

```
2022-05-27 17:45:33.317  INFO 4180 --- [           main] reactor.Flux.TakeUntilOther.1            : onSubscribe(SerializedSubscriber)
2022-05-27 17:45:33.317  INFO 4180 --- [           main] reactor.Flux.TakeUntilOther.1            : request(unbounded)
2022-05-27 17:45:43.469  INFO 4180 --- [    parallel-12] reactor.Flux.TakeUntilOther.1            : onNext(10)
2022-05-27 17:45:44.485  INFO 4180 --- [     parallel-1] reactor.Flux.TakeUntilOther.1            : onNext(11)
.
.
.
2022-05-27 17:46:42.098  INFO 4180 --- [    parallel-10] reactor.Flux.TakeUntilOther.1            : onNext(68)
2022-05-27 17:46:43.103  INFO 4180 --- [    parallel-11] reactor.Flux.TakeUntilOther.1            : onNext(69)
2022-05-27 17:46:43.306  INFO 4180 --- [     parallel-1] reactor.Flux.TakeUntilOther.1            : onComplete()
```